# How to send packets in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, packets

I've read some on the internet, and I'm wondering how to send packets over TCP in C#. This is what I've done so far:

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("myipaddresssecret", 7172);
        Byte[] data = "140049081141799b622d422fcd918d9fb1c55bc3f422";
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        client.Close();
```

(got the data from Wireshark)

So the question is: How to send TCP packets over internet in C#, or WHAT is wrong with my code?

Comment: I said I was wondering how to send packets over TCP in C# ??

Comment: What are your grounds for believing that this doesn't work? What result were you expecting and how does it compare to what actually happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sending your own crafted TCP packet on Windows, you will need a driver like WinPcap. If you use WinPcap, you can use one of the many .Net wrappers or code your own. Sending a raw frame only with objects provided by the Windows API (like sockets) will not work.

Just look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(VS.85).aspx

The only alternative would be to create your own network monitoring driver, or to buy a commercial version of WinPcap which does not require installation but integrates seamlessly into your program.

> On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows
>   XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and
>   Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3),
>   the ability to send traffic over raw
>   sockets has been restricted in several
>   ways:
>
> TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.

For the case you change your mind, maybe you can find something you need in this library: http://www.eex-dev.net/fileadmin/user_upload/apidoc/NetworkLibrary/index.html

It includes a WinPcap wrapper and a lot of methods and objects to craft and analyze packets. May it be useful.

Comment: Ok how to install it, and do u know why my data is too long ?? I copied it from wireshark.

Comment: Are you sure he even wants to craft packet headers and whatnot? It kind of looks to me that this guy just wants to send plain, normal data via standard TCP.